# Installing QuantLib python SWIG module on Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I am new to GAE. I wish to use the QuantLib python library (SWIG) as a module inside google app engine. I was following this blog post to set up QuantLib-SWIG on Ubuntu. http://blog.quantess.net/2012/09/26/quantlib-get-it-working-on-ubuntu/

I have compiled the modules for python using `make -c Python` after installing the required boost c++ libraries as mentioned in the post.

I've copied the QuantLib folder to my app folder. The QunatLib folder contains the following files:

```
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
QuantLib.py
QuantLib.pyc
_QuantLib.so*
```

This is my app directory structure:

```
app.yaml
index.py
QuantLib/
```

However, when I do an

```
import QunatLib
```

in the index.py in my app folder, I get the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named _QuantLib 
      args = ('No module named _QuantLib',) 
      message = 'No module named _QuantLib'
```

I also get this is dev_appserver logs:

```
ImportError: No module named _QuantLib
```

_QuantLib is a `.so` file. Is there a way I can fix this problem? Or any other way to use QuantLib libraries for GAE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

There are a limited number of 3rd party libraries that are not pure python.  You cannot add your own non pure python libraries to appengine runtime.

Here is the current list of included 3rd party libs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

You can add any **pure python** libraries in your own code base.

Comment: Thank you Tim. That was very helpful. I guess I'll look at other alternatives.